# Changing key binding one specific key

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

How can I change key bindings for a single key? I know that there are software like xmodmap and so on, but with this I can't map my key bindings, because with xmodmap I first have to press the keys that I want to change, but I can't because the key f doesn't work anymore. So I just want to change f (which doesn't work) to another, more useless key.
How to do that?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xmodmap doesn't need "to press the keys". Did you read man [xmodmap(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmodmap)?

All you have to do is to set key, like for example `F12` to `f`.

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep F12
keycode  96 = F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 XF86Switch_VT_12 F12 F12 XF86Switch_VT_12
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 96 = f F"
```

First line shows keycode for F12 and second (command) sets *keycode 96* to be *'f'*.

You can see all keycodes with *-pke* option. It can also be used as backup.

```
# save current key map to file:
$ xmodmap -pke > xmodmap.bak

# you can view it with:
$ less xmodmap.bak

# restore from backup:
$ xmodmap xmodmap.bak
```

Last thing you have to do is put it in `~/.Xmodmap` so your setting will load automatically with X server start.

```
$ echo "keycode 96 = f F f F" >> ~/.Xmodmap
```

This should hopefully solve automatic load of the setting.

--

Check [xmodmap Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xmodmap) or [xmodmap tutorial](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_xmodmap_tutorial.html) for reference.

Comment: Hi, Thx For answer, but it didn't work. F12 makes more brightness (F11 lower). keycode is now 96 = F f F f " but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Seems like F12 is not keycode 96 on your keyboard. Check updated answer to find out more. You should easily get to what is wrong with your command line.

Comment: Show us result of `$ xmodmap -pke | grep F12`.