# Help with xmodmap example from archwiki

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

This article: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xmodmap#Reassigning_modifiers_to_keys_on_your_keyboard

Has an example:

```
clear lock
clear control
add control = Caps_Lock Control_L Control_R
keycode 66 = Control_L Caps_Lock NoSymbol NoSymbol
```

That maps `caps_lock` physical to the function `control` and  physical `shift + caps_lock` to the function `caps_lock`.  My problem is that I don't know how this example works.

My intuitive (but incorrect) understanding of how these lines should work is:

you clear the `lock`/`control` modifiers. I naively think that `lock` means `caps lock` but this is probably incorrect.

Then the `add control = Caps_Lock Control_L Control_R` means 'the keysyms `Caps_Lock` `Control_L` and `Control_R` will trigger the `control` modifier.

Then the last line: `keycode 66 = Control_L Caps_Lock NoSymbol NoSymbol` should mean (in my head but not in reality) map the physical key with keycode 66 (the physical caps lock key) so that alone it gives keysym `Control_L` (triggering the control modifier per the previous line), and `shift+keycode 66` should (and here's where I'm confused) also just trigger the `Caps_Lock` keycode,  and therefore the control modifier.

I've experimented with various modifications to this with further unexpected results.

I find the documentation for xmodmap (both in the manpage and archwiki) to be terse and unhelpful.

So I am wondering if someone could explain what's going on with this code. Also the functions of the `control` and `lock` modifiers because I've realized that the `lock` modifier is not just caps lock.

I know that XKB is the recommended config tool now, and that doing complicated things with xmodmap is discouraged so maybe this is just one step too far.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [Linux: xmodmap Tutorial](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_xmodmap_tutorial.html), and maybe this [topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651492/changing-key-binding-one-specific-key/651564#651564) and you will understand it better.